# extracting year from unix time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a Log table and this is it's description:

```
user_id(bigint)
  time (bigint)
```

My question is, how can I extract the year from the `time` column in PostgreSQL?

This works in **MySQL**:

```
 SELECT l.user_id, year(from_unixtime(l.time)) 
 FROM log l;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date_part('year', to_timestamp(1365682413));
```

[to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) is our friend here and has taken a unix time since at least version 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
select extract(year from timestamp 'epoch' + "time" * interval '1 second')
from log;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm newbie in PostgreSQL, and this worked perfectly